# Firefox: Close all tabs and *active last*

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

```
async function closeAllTabs(activeTab)
{
    const tabs = await browser.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true, active: false });
    for (const tab of tabs)
        browser.tabs.remove(tab.id);

    browser.tabs.remove(activeTab.id);  // Close the active tab last so that it would be first in the Recently Closed list.
}

browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(closeAllTabs);
```

How do I make sure the active tab is closed last?
With the code above, it works intermittently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `await` and pass all ids at once as an array:

```js
async function closeAllTabs(activeTab)
{
    const tabs = await browser.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true, active: false });
    await browser.tabs.remove(tabs.map(tab => tab.id));
    await browser.tabs.remove(activeTab.id);
}
```

Comment: Great! Thank you.
I'm currently using:
***
async function closeAllTabs(activeTab, clickData)
{
 const tabs = await browser.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true, active: false });
 await Promise.all(tabs.map(tab => browser.tabs.remove(tab.id)));

 if (clickData.button === 0)
  await browser.tabs.remove(activeTab.id); // MV - Close the active tab last so that it would be first in the Recently Closed list.
}

browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(closeAllTabs);
***
Should the non-active tabs be closed from left to right? I briefly tested it and noticed some abnormality in that.

Comment: I meant: Should the non-active tabs be closed from left to right? I briefly tested it and noticed some random results.

Comment: There is no such guarantee with asynchronous API. If you want to enforce this ordering then either add `await` inside the loop in your original code and/or optionally sort the `tabs` array by `index` property.

Comment: Actually, remove() accepts an array of ids so I've changed the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks again. I appreciate your help.